# Unable to do SITL simulation with Dronekit + APM Planner on Mac

Tags: python, dronekit-python, dronekit

I want to do SITL simulation with Dronekit + MissionPlanner on Mac, and tried to follow [this page](http://python.dronekit.io/develop/sitl_setup.html) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFDWs_DG2QY).
But I couldn't do that.

The procedures I did are listed below.

`$ pip2 install dronekit`
`$ pip2 install dronekit-sitl`
`$ pip2 install MAVProxy`
launch APM Planner2.0
`$ dronekit-sitl copter --home=-35.363261,149.165230,584,353`
`$ mavproxy.py --master tcp:127.0.0.1:5760 --sitl 127.0.0.1:5501 --out 127.0.0.1:14550 --out 127.0.0.1:14551`
`$ python2 ~/dronekit-python/examples/simple_goto/simple_goto.py`

And then unable to link

```
Starting copter simulator (SITL)
SITL already Downloaded and Extracted.
Ready to boot.
Connecting to vehicle on: tcp:127.0.0.1:5760

>>> Link timeout, no heartbeat in last 5 seconds
>>> No heartbeat in 30 seconds, aborting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drone/dronekit-python/examples/simple_goto/simple_goto.py", line 38, in <module>
    vehicle = connect(connection_string, wait_ready=True)
  File "/Users/ysnishi/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 2845, in connect
    vehicle.initialize(rate=rate, heartbeat_timeout=heartbeat_timeout)
  File "/Users/ysnishi/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/dronekit/__init__.py", line 2117, in initialize
    raise APIException('Timeout in initializing connection.')
dronekit.APIException: Timeout in initializing connection.
```

How could I solve this? Do you mind if giving me some advices?

#### Cause (?)

I have an error below in installing MAVProxy and dronekit

```
dronekit 2.9.1 has requirement pymavlink==2.0.6, but you'll have pymavlink 2.2.14 which is incompatible.
```

#### Note

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

APM Planner v2.0.25

droneapi      1.5.0
dronekit      2.9.1
dronekit-sitl 3.2.0
future        0.15.2
lxml          4.2.5
MAVProxy      1.6.7
monotonic     1.2
pip           18.0
protobuf      3.6.1
psutil        5.4.7
pymavlink     2.2.14
pyparsing     2.2.2
pyserial      3.4
requests      2.5.1
setuptools    39.0.1
six           1.11.0

Comment: Can you try to run the program without running APM Planner ? There is a chance that there is a conflict connection between APM Planner and Dronekit connection in tcp:127.0.0.1:5760

Comment: I managed to connect them correctly by changing the last command as below. `$ python2 ~/dronekit-python/examples/simple_goto/simple_goto.py --connect udp:127.0.0.1:14551` Thank you !

Comment: Please add that as an answer to mark this question as solved